# FreeBSD missing PCIIDS

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox

I was trying FreeBSD in VirtualBox and so when I was compiling the VirtualBox guest additions (through ports), I got an error.

PCIIDS could not be found on any of the FreeBSD servers, and so, my compilation could not continue. What would be a solution here?

Comment: I confirm that it has been fixed in the ports. Just re-sync your ports tree and rebuild the "virtualbox-ose-additions" port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this exact same problem today while trying to make subversion so I don't think it has anything to do with Oracle.

From reading the web, sunpoet (author) has released a newer version from that which was included in my ports:

[FreeBSD mailing list](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports/2013-October/087236.html)

I had to do:

```
portsnap fetch
portsnap extract
```

then I was able to make install misc/pciids just fine.